# Help on using boost relaxed heap

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph

I'm implementing a few graph algorithms at the moment and am wanting a container with the complexity of a fibonacci heap or a relaxed heap (specifically I want at least O(logN) for push and pop and O(1) for reduce_key).

I'm not keen on implementing this myself if at all possible (development and testing overhead and time) and I notice that the boost graph library references a couple of likely looking datastructures in the pending directory. The relaxed heap in relaxed_heap.hpp looks the ticket, but I can't quite work out how to use it. It has the following public functions (precised a little for clarity):

```
void push(const value_type& x);
value_type& top();
void pop();
```

Which are clear enough and implement my desired push and pop. Additionally there are:

```
void update(const value_type& x);
void remove(const value_type& x);
```

I'm presuming that I can implement a reduce_key using update but I'm not clear how. My particular issue is that I assume the value is copied upon calling push. What I feel I need is a pointer to the copy of the value in the heap so that I can modify it by reference and then call update to have it shuffled back to where it belongs. However such a pointer does not seem to be available?

Anyone with experience of relaxed heaps in general, or boost relaxed heaps in particular willing to put me out of my misery with an explanation or a nice code snippet?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: I'm confused -- do `std::push_heap` and `std::pop_heap` not meet your requirements? (I'm not sure what "reduce key" means)

Comment: @Billy: "reduce key" means to reduce the value of an element of the heap, and then restore the heap structure. It's `O(log N)` time in a simple (binomial) heap; other types of heap can manage it in amortised constant time.

Comment: OK. I think I've worked out how this works: the values that you put in the relaxed_heap are stored in a vector which is indexed on the 'id' of the value stored. This is not the value on which the heap ordering is performed but is a way of going unambiguously from your element to where it has been stored in the heap.

This to do a reduce key, you take your original value in the heap and keep the id the same (so that the relaxed_heap can find the relevant copy) but change the value on which the ordering is performed.

That'll teach me to use undocumented containers... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex, 
  if you checkout/download/browse boost library, there's a libs/graph/test directory.    One of the tests is relaxed_heap_test.cpp which seems to have coverage of the update member function.

-s-